# por que al colocar esta sentencia me genera error 1064 (42000)at line 1

Tags: php, mysql

El div wrapper se usará para facilitar el estilo de toda la página. El div menu obviamente contiene un menú con enlaces a páginas que todavía tenemos que crear, pero ayuda un poco a ver hacia dónde vamos. El div userbar se usará para una pequeña barra superior que contiene cierta información como el nombre de usuario y un enlace a la página de cierre de sesión. La página de contenido abarca el contenido real de la página, obviamente.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="nl" lang="nl">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="A short description." />
    <meta name="keywords" content="put, keywords, here" />
    <title>PHP-MySQL forum</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>My forum</h1>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <a class="item" href="/forum/index.php">Home</a> -
        <a class="item" href="/forum/create_topic.php">Create a topic</a> -
        <a class="item" href="/forum/create_cat.php">Create a category</a>

        <div id="userbar">
        <div id="userbar">Hello Example. Not you? Log out.</div>
    </div>
        <div id="content">
```

Comment: El error 1064 es de MySQL, pero en tu pregunta no veo ningún código MySQL. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta, indicando cuál es el código que produce el error.